# Install 3rd Party Libraries with Transitive Dependencies / Dependency Tree?

Tags: java, maven

I am a Maven newbie and spent hours to learn the basics, but I still have not found any good documentation how to install locally a 3rd Party JAR with all its (transitive) dependencies.

I know `mvn install:install-file` does install a single JAR. But how to install locally in the repsoitory something like this:

```
+ Parent.jar
  + ChildA.jar (Requuired by Parent)
    + ChildB.jar (Required by Child A)
```

To make it more complcated and real life: Parent.jar and ChildA.jar are legacy/commercial Jars not available in the public maven Repository but the Child B is a jar that is found in the public repository (for example like a logging jar).

UPDATE: I do not only want to install them locally (with a system dependency) but to also "correctly" integregrate them with maven so i can redistribute this dependency tree to other developers or the public (and I assume this is important for maven), so that maven knows and understands the dependecytree (to avoid version conflicts, unnecessary downloads etc...)

Any links or information how that exaclty describe how this can be done would be great.

Thank you very much!!
Marks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a commercial jar, you may be in violation of the license if you deploy it to a central repository, and the only recourse is to deploy to your company's repo (if you have one setup).

In order to do that you need to define a pom for childA, specifying childB as a dependency, then run the install:install-file goal for that. Then do the same for parent, with childA as it's dependency.

Once you do that, you can then take those items, and upload them pretty easily to your company's central repo through it's GUI (both Nexus and Artifactory support this through the GUI).

Comment: Thanks, that was really what I was looking for: I realised I have to write POMs for all the "non maven provided" Libraries myself and install them with these POMs.

Answer (score 1):

Since you actually want to actually publish so that others in the public can use it with the defined dependencies, you pretty much have to get the 3rd party jars into a publicly available repo.

[Here are instructions](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/Uploading+3rd-party+Artifacts+to+The+Central+Repository) on how to accomplish that.

Please note though, the licensing for the code may not allow you to publish it to a central repo.  This is checked before it can be deployed.

Comment: You need to make sure that you're allowed to upload the jar to the central repo, as provided in the license. Otherwise, you're only allowed to deploy to your company's central repo.

Comment: That is correct and Sonatype will verify that there are no such restrictions before they will publish it.  That is documented in the link I posted, but I will edit and add that note to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you maybe look for [this](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies).

Maven will load all needed dependecies into the local repo itself if they are availebale in the online repo. If you want to install your own projects, setup the reactor with profiles to have all wanted modules in it and run `mvn install -P yourprofile` on it. More about profiles can be found [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html). Afaik is there no way, to install projects including their dependencies into the local repo.

Comment: How is that in any way helpful?

Comment: with system dependecies you can use jars that are not in a repo, not only jdk stuff.

Answer (score -1):

if you need to install it to a local Maven repository, just use

```
mvn dependency:go-offline
```

Comment: This doesn't install a dependency into any repository, it resolves the dependencies so you can work offline.

Comment: Yes and you can work offline because the dependencies were downloaded and put in local repository. maybe you got confused by mine use of install ? It did not mean maven's install phase. I hope you know the difference of local and remote repository : http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html

Comment: I respectfully submit that the confusion is on your end. The question is how to install an artifact that is *not* currently in *any* repo into both the local repo and then the central repo. The dependency plugin does nothing for the user, since the artifacts are not available in any repository to be downloaded in the first place.

Comment: Well, it's a newbie question and a bit vague, so I answered as I understood. Plus my answer starts wit "if".