# Install 3rd Party Libraries with Transitive Dependencies / Dependency Tree? Automated?

Tags: maven

I have encountered similar problem as stated in following question: [Install 3rd Party Libraries with Transitive Dependencies / Dependency Tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819682/install-3rd-party-libraries-with-transitive-dependencies-dependency-tree)

I will quote most important part from it below:

> I know `mvn install:install-file` does install a single JAR. But how
>   to install locally in the repsoitory something like this:
>
> ```
> + Parent.jar
>   + ChildA.jar (Requuired by Parent)
>     + ChildB.jar (Required by Child A)
> ```
>
> To make it more complcated and real life: Parent.jar and ChildA.jar
>   are legacy/commercial Jars not available in the public maven
>   Repository but the Child B is a jar that is found in the public
>   repository (for example like a logging jar).
>
> UPDATE: I do not only want to install them locally (with a system
>   dependency) but to also "correctly" integregrate them with maven so i
>   can redistribute this dependency tree to other developers or the
>   public (and I assume this is important for maven), so that maven knows
>   and understands the dependecytree (to avoid version conflicts,
>   unnecessary downloads etc...)

I have similar case jars are legacy and commercial I will deploy them to internal company repository.

Solution is simple which I figured before finding a question, to write pom for every jar and import them using syntax `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DpomFile=<path-to-pomfile>`. But in my case there is over 200 jars with more than 10.000 class files in total. That's why I was wondering wether there is software which could provide me with easy parse-able and/or process-able output telling which jars depend on which. Otherwise it could take insane amount of time do it manually. Open every jar, decompile every class, find which classes it referenced, are they from other jars (which?) or not.

I think this should be possible to automate since classloaders do something similar. If it need to load a certain class it have to load class that are used by this certain class, so there is a way to know  which classes are referenced. And you can tell which classes belongs to which archives.

I'm also aware that I might not be not able to import them because of some circular dependencies between classes from different jars. I'm fine with that if software says - NO if it's not possible. That's actually another reason why I don't want to do it manually and acknowledge after 2 weeks that I just waste my time.

So any idea if such software exists?